# Can I load my controller, model and view directly from the plugin?

Tags: plugin, mvc

I am trying to create a plugin that adds a new view to my component (addon).

Can I load my controller, model and view directly from the plugin?

*For example:*

```
require_once("/pludins/myplugintype/myplugin/controllers/controller.php");
require_once("/pludins/myplugintype/myplugin/models/models.php");
require_once("/pludins/myplugintype/myplugin/view/view.html.php");
require_once("/pludins/myplugintype/myplugin/tmpl/default.php");
```

And the next question.
Will I be able to create a menu item using **onAfterGetMenuTypeOptions**?

Comment: Inside your plugin code you're just running PHP, so you can pretty much run whatever PHP code you want. Have you tried it? Did it do what you wanted?

Comment: Please edit your question to include more context, more research, your coding attempt, and a single question.  When you better explain exactly what needs to happen for your specific plugin, volunteers will be able to offer higher quality, more specific advice.  Please narrow down your question to the first single issue that you are experiencing.  It is perfectly fine to ask multiple questions dealing with a single development task.  Break your task down in pieces and ask how to get passed a single road block that you are experiencing.